# Как защитить проект?

Tags: javascript, html

Создавал игру 3 месяца на js,html,css. Я загрузил её на свой сайт и подключил рекламу. Она устроена таким образом ,что для подключение рекламы я просто добавляю строку с подключение её апи, потом в файле js файле её вызываю. Другой пользователь убрав строку кода где подключается реклама, `<script  src="https//apireklana.js"></script>`  получил по сути доступ ко всему проекту. И потом залил его на свой сайт. Вопрос существуют ли способы какие нибудь защиты например проверять был ли код изменён итд?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<script  src="https//apireklana.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="3.js"></script>





    
</script>
</body>
</html>

файды 3.js

//код игры
function reklama(){
    
}

 reklama();
```

Comment: Достаточно было для игры перенести бизнес логику на сервер,  и от туда тянуть все необходимые данные, и даже если бы вытащили весь сайт, сервер бы не вытащили точно

Comment: Как гугл сервисы делают - АПИ которая работает только с определенного хоста. Как платные плагины js делают - минификация кода и часть кода обфусцирована (та часть без который плагин не может работать). Напишите письмо на тот сайт, который украл код + посмотрите через whois где сайт лежит в строке abuse будет e-mail куда писать. Желательно делать все меры: (серверная часть которая будет подгружать по хосту, которую нельзя будет вытянуть, обфускация, страница на сайте по где будет изложено что запрещено копирование файлов без согласия ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. можно обфусцировать код, так что для глаза он уже будет нечитаемым, хотя функционал будет ровно таким же - в сети есть сервисы, которое это позволяют делать, поищите

статья о том, что это такое
https://habr.com/ru/post/112530/

конечно все равно можно разобрать код, но это требует много усилий, так что если проект не денежный или слабоденежный, то обфускация - это хороший выход

2. если проект денежный, то у нас есть 4 Часть ГК (гражданский кодекс), статьи по авторскому праву и суд :)

Comment: думаю может ещё сервером как нибудь проверять

Comment: @Сергей Александров, серверная часть хороша, когда вы формируете динамический контент для конкретного пользователя или под конкретную ситуацию, тогда да, клиентская часть - это лишь оболочка без контента, а все самое "ценное" передаёт сервер, тогда становится тяжеловато что-то утащить, но опять таки можно, если очень хочется. Вообще все упирается исключительно в целесообразность, если труд не окупается - его никто делать не будет.